# When does a subspace of the affine space form a regular sequence in a ring of regular functions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, complete-intersection

Let $J$ be an ideal in the ring $\mathbb{C}[u] := \mathbb{C}[u_1,...,u_n]$ of regular functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

- Given a subspace $\mathbb{C}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $I$ its ideal in $\mathbb{C}[u]$, when can we say that the $n-k$ generators of $I$ form a regular sequence in $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$ ? Can we express this condition in terms of the zero sets of $I$ and $J$ ?
- Suppose that the generators of $I$ form indeed a regular sequence in $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$. Is it still true in the ring $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}] / J\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ (considered as a $\mathbb{C}[u]$-module) ?

Comment: Your claim in the second sentence is only valid if $J$ is a radical ideal.  Regularity of a sequence is equivalent to the vanishing of the higher homology modules of the Koszul complex associated to the sequence.  This vanishing is preserved by every flat base change (and implied by vanishing after any faithfully flat base change).  The ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[u]/J \to \mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]/J\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ is flat (usually not faithfully flat).  Thus, the image in $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]/J\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ of a regular sequence in $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ is still a regular sequence.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Starr. I don’t understand your statement about $J$ being radical. Seems that the flatness of the ring homomorphism is enough (does this depend on radicality of $J$ ?).

Comment: I also don’t understand your statement “and implied by vanishing after any faithlully flat base change”.

Comment: For $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ to be isomorphic to the ring of regular functions on the zero zet $V(J)$ you need $J$ to be radical. For a counterexample consider $n = 1$. Then $V(u_1) = V(u_1^2)$, but obviously $\mathbb{C}[u_1]/(u_1) \ncong \mathbb{C}[u_1]/(u_1^2)$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I erased this sentence, which is not necessary anyway. Suppose then that $J$ is not necessarily radical. Is there a way to relate the fact that $I$ is generated by a regular sequence in $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$ and the zero sets $\mathbb{C}^k$ and $V(J)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the **first question**:

The zero sets of $I$ and $J$ are not enough to know whether the generators of $I$ remain a regular sequence in $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$. In particular, the zero set of $J$ is not sensitive to changes in $J$ that do not affect its radical, but these changes can be relevant to whether the generators of $I$ remain a regular sequence.

This is shown by the example Jason Starr gave in answer to [your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311069/on-finite-dimensional-commutative-algebras-and-regular-sequences). For simplicity, consider the case $m=2$, $k=1$, i.e. $\mathbb{C}[u] = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and let $I=(y)$, $J=(x^2,xy)$ (per Jason's example). Then the zero set of $J$ is $\{x=0\}$, and the zero set of $I$ is $\{y=0\}$. In this situation, the generator $y$ of $I$ does not remain regular in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/J$, since it becomes a zerodivisor.

On the other hand, if $J=(x)$ (note this is the radical of the previous choice of $J$, thus it has the same zero set), then $y$ remains regular in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/J$.

A *necessary* condition on $V(I)$ and $V(J)$ for the generators of $I$ to remain regular in $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ (the example above shows it is not sufficient) is that

$$\dim V(J) - \dim V(I)\cap V(J) \geq n-k.$$

Proof: The quotient of the noetherian ring $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$, of Krull dimension $\dim V(J)$, by a regular sequence of length $r$, has Krull dimension $\leq \dim V(J) - r$. Proof by induction on $r$: quotienting by a single regular element $a$ must reduce the dimension. If the chains of primes containing $a$ included any of maximal length, then $a$ would be contained in a minimal prime ideal, which would be an associated prime of zero, and therefore $a$ would be a zerodivisor, contrary to assumption. Thus, if $I$ is generated by a regular sequence of length $r=n-k$, the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[u]/(I+J)$ ($=\dim V(I)\cap V(J)$) must be at least $r=n-k$ lower than the dimension of $V(J)$. This is the stated claim.

Jason answered the **second question** in comments: a regular sequence in $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ remains regular when you invert $u$, as it does in all flat extensions. See for example Proposition 1.1.2 in Winfried Bruns and Jurgen Herzog's book *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*. The argument is basically that an element being regular means multiplication by it is injective, and flat base change preserves injectivity, followed by induction on the length of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I’m wondering though how to translate “regularity of I” in $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$ in terms of intersections of spaces in $\mathbb{C}^n$. In my situation for instance, I know that $J$ is generated by monomials whose degrees are in a certain subspace $\mathbb{Z}_J \subset \mathbb{Z}_{>0}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^k$. Moreover, I have shown the following : if a coordinate subspace $\mathbb{C}^d \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ intersects $\mathbb{C}^k$ non trivially, then it intersects $\mathbb{Z}_J$ non trivially. Does this kind of statements say something about regularity ?

Comment: It helps that $J$ is a monomial ideal. Is $I$ as well? Or is it at least homogeneous? (Incidentally, I'm having trouble following your inclusions. $\mathbb{Z}_J$ seems to be a subspace of the lattice of exponents. I thought $\mathbb{C}^k$ was a linear subspace of the affine variety $\mathbb{C}^n$. Can you state the claim in more detail?)

Comment: $I$ is the ideal generated by $n-k$ polynomials of degree $1$, since it is the ideal of a linear subspace $\mathbb{C}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^n$. On the other hand, J is a monomial ideal generated by monomials whose exponents are in $\mathbb{Z}_J \subset \mathbb{Z}^k_{>0} \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$. The claim is that the generators of $I$ form a regular sequence in the quotient $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$.

Comment: The claim I really want to prove is with a slightly different $J$: the $\mathbb{C}[u]$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ defined by monomials with exponents in a “half lattice” $\mathbb{Z}_J \subset \mathbb{Z}^k \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ (note that $J$ is not an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ anymore so localizing might not help, and that $J \cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ plays the role of the ideal $J$ from above). The real claim is: the generators of $I$ form a regular sequence in the quotient $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}] /J$. Proving the statement for $\mathbb{C}[u] / J \cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ might be enough.

Comment: I'm still confused on whether your $I$ is homogeneous. When you say "linear subspace" it sounds like the answer is yes, but when above you wrote $\mathbb{Z}_J\subset\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^k\subset\mathbb{C}^k$, it made it seem like your $\mathbb{C}^k$ is a merely affine subspace and then the answer would be no.

I'm also unsure what you mean "half lattice".

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear, and $\mathbb{C}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ are the complexifications. In these spaces, we have lattices $\mathbb{Z}^k \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$, viewed as degrees of monomials. $I$ is the ideal of $\mathbb{C}^k$. Its $(n-k)$ generators have degree $1$. For $J$, I have a certain function $p \in \mathbb{R}^{k*}$. $\mathbb{Z}_J \subset \mathbb{Z}^k$ is the sublattice $\{m \in \mathbb{Z}^k : p(m) \geq 0 \}$, and $J$ is defined as the $\mathbb{C}[u]$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ generated by monomials $u^m$, with $m \in \mathbb{Z}_J$.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, your $I$ *is* a homogeneous ideal, with generators *homogeneous* of degree 1. Am I understanding you right that you are saying you want to know if the forms that define this ideal stay regular when you quotient by monomials whose exponents are in the subspace it defines?

Comment: I guess you've made that clear, but I'm just asking repeatedly because I'm surprised by the "meta-ness" - the lattice of exponents is sitting inside the variety on which the coordinate functions are functions! I've never seen this before. I'm curious about the motivation.

Comment: The ideal $I$ is generated by degree $1$ homogeneous elements. Be careful about $J$ though: it is a $\mathbb{C}[u]$ submodule of $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$, **generated** by monomials whose exponents sit in a **part** of the lattice sitting inside the subspace defining $I$. Regarding the motivation, the quotient $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}] / I$ is the quantum cohomology of a toric manifold, and the quotient $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}] / (I+J)$ is an element of a filtration of the latter. Regularity will help me compute a Serre spectral sequence appearing in the computation of the filtered quantum cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for the comments on motivation. Since $I$ and $J$ are both homogeneous, regularity of the generators of $I$ might be easy to determine geometrically if $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ is Cohen-Macaulay. Do you know if it is?

Comment: If $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ is CM, then the generators of $I$ will stay regular in $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ if and only if the codimension of $V(I+J)$ in $V(J)$ equals the codimension of $V(I)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$..

Comment: I think this condition is necessary even if $\mathbb{C}[u]/J$ is not CM.

Comment: I don’t know if the quotient is CM. What I know is that the dimension of $V(I+J \cap \mathbb{C}[u])$ is 0, but I don’t know what the dimension of $V(J \cap \mathbb{C}[u])$ is (let me remind you that the ideal is $J \cap\mathbb{C}[u]$, since $J$ is defined as a $\mathbb{C}[u]$ submodule of $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$).

Comment: Without dimension info about $V(J\cap \mathbb{C}[u])$ (at least enough to know that it is at least $n-k$), I don't think you can guarantee that the generators of $I$ remain regular. There is no way for them to be regular if $\mathbb{C}[u]/(J\cap \mathbb{C}[u])$ doesn't have at least $n-k$ dimensions.

Comment: I will add this necessary condition (under the homogeneity hypothesis) to my answer, with an argument. I will use the conventions you set up in the OP (rather than your new definition of $J$) so readers don't have to refer to the comments in order to understand.

Comment: I found a way to write the condition without the homogeneity hypothesis. At this point I'm not sure what else to do to try to answer the question in the OP. If you would like engagement with more of the details of your particular case, consider posting a new question?

Comment: I don’t really understand what your condition is. Are you claiming that a necessary condition is that the dimension of the quotient is at least $n-k$ or that the dimension of the zero set $V(J \cap \mathbb{C}[u])$ is at least $n-k$ (are these dimensions equal ?) ? Thanks for you help and interest in my question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the flatness of the extension. I emphasize that we’re passing from $\mathbb{C}[u] / J \cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ to $\mathbb{C} [u,u^{-1}] / J$, where the last quotient is a quotient by a submodule and not an ideal. Therefore the homomorphism from the former to the latter is a homomorphism of modules and not of rings. Is it a problem ? If it’s still ok, what is the argument, can I find a proof somewhere that flat extensions preserve regularity ?

Comment: The dimension of the ring $\mathbb{C}[u]/(J\cap\mathbb{C}[u])$ and the dimension of the zero set $V(J\cap \mathbb{C}[u])$ are equal; in fact, I believe this fact is the motivation for the definition of the dimension of the ring.

Comment: Regarding your second question, the answer is addressed to the question as you asked it in the OP, where $J$ was an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[u]$.

Comment: What I mean when I talk about the dimension of the ring is it’s dimension as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, whence my question. Regarding my second question, what is the reason why a flat extension preserves regularity ?

Comment: Ah. All my use of the word "dimension" with reference to a ring has been referring to Krull dimension. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) This is usually different from dimension as a $\mathbb{C}$-space. The dimension as vector space will be infinite unless the Krull dimension is zero.

Comment: Flat extensions preserve regularity for the reason given by Jason Starr in the comments on the OP. Regularity is the same as vanishing of higher homology of the Koszul complex. We can pass to the Koszul complex for the extension by taking tensor product of original Koszul complex by the extension. If it is flat, tensor product preserves exactness, i.e. it preserves all vanishing of the homology.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that vanishing of the higher homology of the Koszul complex implies regularity ? All i’ve seen so far is that regularity implies vanishing, but not the converse.

Comment: I was just looking at this. I'm not sure, so never mind that argument. But the "regular stays regular in flat extensions" is still true. See proposition 1.1.2 of Bruns & Herzog's book *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*. The argument is basically that an element being regular means mult. by it is injective, and that property is preserved by flat extension.

Comment: I'm unclear about the way that the difference between $J$ and $J\cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ affects the problem, but in general, yes, if $R$ is a ring, $x_1,x_2,\dots\in R$ is a reg. seq. on a module $M$, and $N$ is a flat $R$-module, then $x_1,x_2,\dots$ is regular on $M\otimes_R N$, with the same arg.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your help. Now, the question is : can we say the same thing with module homomorphisms... if $I$ forms a regular sequence in the module $\mathbb{C}[u] / J \cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ (a quotient by an ideal), does it remain regular in the quotient $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}] / J$...

Comment: So here, what should be $N$ ?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure how to account for the diff. btw. $J$ and $J\cap \mathbb{C}[u]$, but if $J$ were contained in $\mathbb{C}[u]$, then you could take $N=\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$...

Comment: So, quick update. The dimension of $\mathbb{C}[u] / J$ is indeed of dimension at least $n-k$. Does this close the problem ?

Comment: No, that's just a necessary condition.

Comment: Ok, and if the dimension was exactly $n-k$ ? I’m trying to avoid proving properties like Cohen-Macaulay and work only with dimensions, hence my question.

Comment: No. This is exactly the situation of the example in the OP, which shows that the zero sets are not enough info by themselves.

Comment: In the situation of the OP the dimension is at least $n-k$, therefore I thought that it could be different when the equality holds.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistyped. I meant, "in the answer above." The answer shows a dimension $=n-k$ example where the sequence is regular and another dimension $=n-k$ example where the sequence is not regular.